# MSAL login in chrome extension: 'redirect_uri' is not valid

Tags: google-chrome-extension, msal-angular

I build a chrome extension use Angular. In this extension I use `@azure/msal-angular` to login.

What can I do to login in chrome extension?

Here is my extension image:[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU5O3.png)

When I **first** click `Login`, console print:

`@azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.1 : Info - Emitting event: msal:loginStart`.

Then click `Login` or `Login using Popup`, console print:

```
BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress. Please ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an interactive API.  For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.
```

When I **first** click `Login using Popup`, the website show:

```
invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.
```

Here is my login code:

```js
loginRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.authService.loginRedirect({
        ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest,
      } as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }

  loginPopup() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.authService.loginPopup({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest } as PopupRequest)
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
    } else {
      this.authService.loginPopup()
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Assuming it's the `action` popup, maybe it doesn't support opening authentication UI, so try doing it in a new window created via chrome.windows.create

Comment: Use chrome.windows.create it is worker. But extension can not redirect use this link:`extension://eibpbaimgiabjlckabimpoaablbmnlne/#code=xx...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` API solve this issue.If you want use Oauth2 in chrome extension ,please watch [chrome identity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-launchWebAuthFlow)